# How to populate a df with rolling head to head between teams?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df with data about matches between teams and I want to make a new column that has the h2h record between teams prior to a match.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['LAC','LAL', 1, '15/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '16/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '17/02/2022'],
                           ['LAL','LAC', 1, '18/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '19/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '20/02/2022'],
                           ['LAL','LAC', 1, '21/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '22/02/2022']],
                   columns = ['winner', 'loser', 'won', 'date'])
```

In this example the head to head prior to each match should be: 0-0, 1-0, 2-0, 1-2, 2-2, 3-3, 3-4

I want to calculate h2h % wins, but I guess getting the number of wins of one team vs the other is the first step. I can calculate the final h2h with a groupby but I'm not sure how to approach calculating per match given that a team might either be in one of the two columns. To note, the format of this df follows a winner/loser format so 'won' is always 1. Alternatively, I can change the df to a long version (one match = two rows) but not sure if that helps. I have other columns as well but I'm not sure if they are relevant for this question (more stats, ids' etc).

Based on @quasi-human reply, I can do the following:

```
df['winner_wins'] = df.groupby(['winner', 'loser'])['won'].cumsum()
df['winner_wins'] = df.groupby(['winner', 'loser'])['winner_wins'].shift(1)
```

to get an accurate record of number of wins of the 'winner' team prior to a match. But I don't know how should I approach getting the same for the 'loser' team

Comment: If there is a draw? If you can also update your post with the expected dataframe, it could be help :)

Comment: No there is no draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `cumsum` and `expanding` methods might be useful for you.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['LAC','LAL', 1, '15/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '16/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '17/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '18/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '19/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '20/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '21/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '22/02/2022']], columns = ['winner', 'loser', 'won', 'date'])

# Calculate h2h records
df = df.sort_values('date').assign(
    LAC_h2h_wins=(df.winner=='LAC').cumsum(),
    LAL_h2h_wins=(df.winner=='LAL').cumsum(),
    LAC_h2h_wins_pct=(df.winner=='LAC').expanding().agg(lambda s: 100 * s.sum() / len(s)),
    LAL_h2h_wins_pct=(df.winner=='LAL').expanding().agg(lambda s: 100 * s.sum() / len(s)),
)

print(df)
```

### Output:

|  | winner | loser | won | date | LAC_h2h_wins | LAL_h2h_wins | LAC_h2h_wins_pct | LAL_h2h_wins_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 15/02/2022 | 1 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 16/02/2022 | 2 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 17/02/2022 | 2 | 1 | 66.6667 | 33.3333 |
| 3 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 18/02/2022 | 2 | 2 | 50 | 50 |
| 4 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 19/02/2022 | 2 | 3 | 40 | 60 |
| 5 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 20/02/2022 | 3 | 3 | 50 | 50 |
| 6 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 21/02/2022 | 3 | 4 | 42.8571 | 57.1429 |
| 7 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 22/02/2022 | 4 | 4 | 50 | 50 |

---

## [EDIT]

Answer to the OP's comment.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe with more data points
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['LAC','LAL', 1, '15/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '16/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '17/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '18/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '19/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '20/02/2022'], ['LAL','LAC', 1, '21/02/2022'], ['LAC','LAL', 1, '22/02/2022'], ['ABC','LAL', 1, '15/02/2022'], ['ABC','LAL', 1, '16/02/2022'], ['LAL','ABC', 1, '17/02/2022'], ['LAL','ABC', 1, '18/02/2022'], ['LAL','ABC', 1, '19/02/2022'], ['ABC','LAL', 1, '20/02/2022'], ['LAL','ABC', 1, '21/02/2022'], ['ABC','LAL', 1, '22/02/2022'], ['ABC','XYZ', 1, '15/02/2022'], ['ABC','XYZ', 1, '16/02/2022'], ['XYZ','ABC', 1, '17/02/2022'], ['XYZ','ABC', 1, '18/02/2022'], ['XYZ','ABC', 1, '19/02/2022'], ['ABC','XYZ', 1, '20/02/2022'], ['XYZ','ABC', 1, '21/02/2022'], ['ABC','XYZ', 1, '22/02/2022'], ['LAC','XYZ', 1, '15/02/2022'], ['LAC','XYZ', 1, '16/02/2022'], ['XYZ','LAC', 1, '17/02/2022'], ['XYZ','LAC', 1, '18/02/2022'], ['XYZ','LAC', 1, '19/02/2022'], ['LAC','XYZ', 1, '20/02/2022'], ['XYZ','LAC', 1, '21/02/2022'], ['LAC','XYZ', 1, '22/02/2022']], columns = ['winner', 'loser', 'won', 'date'])

# In order to group by games, make sorted game titles like "LAC-LAL"
df['game'] = df.apply(lambda r: '-'.join(sorted([r.winner, r.loser])), axis=1)

# Ensure that df is sorted game and date (date must align in the ascending order)
df = df.sort_values(['game', 'date'], ignore_index=True)

# Assign 1 if the left team in the game title, otherwise 0. For example, "LAC" is the left team in the game title "LAC-LAL"
df['left_win'] = df.apply(lambda r: f'{r.winner}-{r.loser}'==r.game, axis=1)

# Do the same thing on the right team.
df['right_win'] = ~df.left_win

# Calculate the cumulative sumation.
df[['left_win_cumsum', 'right_win_cumsum']] = df.groupby('game')[['left_win', 'right_win']].cumsum()

# Shift and fill the first games as 0
df[['h2h_winner', 'h2h_loser']] = df.groupby('game')[['left_win_cumsum', 'right_win_cumsum']].shift().fillna(0).astype(int)

# Check the order in a pair of winner and loser columns. If the order is different from the game title, reverse the cumsum values
f = lambda r: [r.h2h_winner, r.h2h_loser] if f'{r.winner}-{r.loser}'==r.game else [r.h2h_loser, r.h2h_winner]
df[['h2h_winner', 'h2h_loser']] = df.apply(f, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)

# Drop all the temporary columns
df = df.drop(['game', 'left_win', 'right_win', 'left_win_cumsum', 'right_win_cumsum'], axis=1)

print(df.to_markdown(stralign='center', numalign='center'))
```

### Output (extracted only LAC - LAL games):

|  | winner | loser | won | date | h2h_winner | h2h_loser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 15/02/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 16/02/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 18 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 17/02/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 19 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 18/02/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 20 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 19/02/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 21 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 20/02/2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 22 | LAL | LAC | 1 | 21/02/2022 | 3 | 3 |
| 23 | LAC | LAL | 1 | 22/02/2022 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I might not have been clear before but my df have many teams and many distinct matchups. The problem with your solution is mainly that it specifies teams by name and that it ignores team order e.g. row index 2 should be 1-2 not 2-1. Also as I need the pre-game h2h these should be shifted one. Though your solution is helpful - I think cumsum is a step in the right direction. I might be able to work out a solution now myself

Comment: @henrycmcjo It sounds complicated, but I tried to solve the problem. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I had a quick look and it seems your solution works fine. Will have a more close look later today and mark it as the correct answer afterwards

Comment: Cool. If you have any questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: I found a mistake, I'll fix it and inform you of it soon.

Comment: hey @quasi-human I appreciate your time. Unfortunately, there is some error in your code. In my dataset, I know and have confirmed that a certain matchup's final h2h is 92-56. However, when I run your code I get mixed h2h scores (e.g. the 85+ vs 50+ record alternating between the two teams). This is also visible in the example you provided: index 7 should be 3-4 not 4-3, index 10 should be 0-2 not 2-0 but the following scores are correct until the team order swaps again where again it counts a win on the opposite side. I understand if you don't want to look into this anymore. Thanks

Comment: I believe the issue is created when shifting the h2h columns. One solution is to use the 'winner_wins' column I have on the initial post, and use a similar function to your f which checks whether h2h_winner is equal to winner_wins and if not swaps h2h columns around

Comment: Thank you for giving a clear explanation. I fixed my code to get the desired output. I just changed the order of the operations of swapping and shifting. I'm not sure if the *mixed h2h scores* issue got solved as well. Please check my updated answer:)

Comment: I haven't thoroughly checked the results in the example df you provided but it seems to be working right. However, for my df the issue I described earlier still appears. The solution I described earlier gives the right results. I will mark your answer as correct since it works on your df and it's 99% of the solution to my df. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
tmp = pd.crosstab(df.index, df["winner"]).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()

# prevent error if there's a team that only wins:
tmp = tmp.merge(
    pd.DataFrame(columns=np.unique(df[["winner", "loser"]])), how="outer"
).fillna(0)

df[["winner_cnt", "loser_cnt"]] = df.apply(
    lambda x: tmp.loc[x.name, x[["winner", "loser"]].values].values, axis=1
).apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  winner loser  won        date  winner_cnt  loser_cnt
0    LAC   LAL    1  15/02/2022           0          0
1    LAC   LAL    1  16/02/2022           1          0
2    LAL   LAC    1  17/02/2022           0          2
3    LAL   LAC    1  18/02/2022           1          2
4    LAL   LAC    1  19/02/2022           2          2
5    LAC   LAL    1  20/02/2022           2          3
6    LAL   LAC    1  21/02/2022           3          3
7    LAC   LAL    1  22/02/2022           3          4
```

Comment: Hello @Andrej Kesely, I appreciate your reply. I like your code but there is an issue that it aggregates all wins/losses with no respect to the matchups. As I said in another comment, my df has many teams with many matchup combinations. If you use your code, on quasi-human's df you can see in the end result it just aggregates wins e.g. index 9 ABC vs XYZ it comes up with 5 wins although that should be 0

Comment: I think the first step is to include both columns in the crosstab i.e. [df["winner"], df['loser']], but I'm not exactly sure how to proceed because I don't fully get your code